# ESLint/Prettier rule to disallow template literals without placeholders

Tags: eslint, prettier, prettier-eslint

Is there an ESLint or Prettier rule that would disallow template literals without a placeholder? I would like to replace backticks in template literals without placeholder with standard quotation marks `''`;

Allowed

```
const templateLiteral = `Some ${string}`;
```

Disallowed

```
const templateLiteral = `Some string`;
```

Turned into

```
const templateLiteral = 'Some string';
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`quotes`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/quotes) eslint rule helps you enforce single quotes. Add the following to your `.eslintrc`:

```json
"rules": {
  "quotes": ["error", "single", { "avoidEscape": true }]
}
```

You can verify that backticks/template literals without any expressions/substitutions are disallowed in [the rule test code](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/9c53ed40255f7913cfb68cec32cba38d11fbc5b2/tests/lib/rules/quotes.js#L48).